# Problema ao ler arquivos em UTF-8 no PHP e direto no navegador

Tags: php, arquivo, navegador-de-internet, utf-8, texto

Preciso salvar um arquivo `.txt` em UTF-8 em PHP. Salvar o arquivo é bem simples, porém, na hora de abrir o arquivo diretamente no navegador (exemplo www.site.com/arquivo.txt) o navegador não consegue reconhecer a codificação UTF-8 e os caracteres "bugam" e acabam ficando assim: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dando uma vasculhada pela internet, encontrei algumas soluções, onde as pessoas recomendam a adição do **BOM** no arquivo. Para adicionar o BOM é bem simples, basta utilizar um destes 3 códigos.

```
fwrite($file, "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); 

fwrite($file, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)); 

fwrite($file, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
```

Após eu adicionar o BOM o navegador interpretou corretamente todos os caracteres e isto resolveu o problema. O resultado final ficou mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao longo do tempo os usuários relataram um problema. O conteúdo deste arquivo pode ser exibidor de duas maneiras no meu sistema. A primeira maneira é a visualização direta pelo navegador igual exibido a cima e a segunda maneira é a visualização normal em uma página HTML. Dentro desta pagina HTML existe um `<textarea>` com o texto do arquivo e ao utilizar os atalhos `CTRL + A` para selecionar tudo e `CTRL + C` para copiar todo o conteúdo do arquivo exibido no `<textarea>`, o caractere de controle do BOM é copiado junto, e na hora de colar o conteúdo copiado o resultado fica mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
.

Como vocês podem ver, o primeiro caractere do texto copiado é um '?' que neste caso é um caractere de controle, que é o equivalente ao BOM.

Minha duvida é:

- Existe alguma maneira de forçar o navegador a ler o arquivo em UTF-8 sem a necessidade de adicionar o BOM no arquivo?

OU

- Existe alguma maneira der ler e exibir o conteúdo do arquivo .txt em *PHP* sem que o BOM seja exibido junto?

Comment: fwrite($file, utf8_encode("Isto não resolve? Abraços!"));

Comment: @jcbrtl infelizmente não resolve.... Esse foi o primeiro método que eu havia testado e infelizmente não resolve o problema.

Comment: tentou usar o mb_convert_encoding? `mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Acredito que quando vc faz a cópia, ele copia o lixo alocado na memória, vc chega a copiar algum espaço antes do texto copiado?

Comment: @WilliamSilva É impossível ser lixo de memória pois acontece com TODOS usuários, e quando eu tiro o BOM, o caractere não vem junto igual eu expliquei acima.

Comment: Eduardo, o caractere `?` é exibido no lugar de qual caractere no arquivo gerado?

Comment: @AndréFilipe esse caractere não é exibido no arquivo pois ele é um caractere de controle. Se você abrir o arquivo no VSCode o caractere não aparece, porem, se você printar o conteúdo do arquivo em uma pagina HTML e copiar todo o texto e depois colar esse texto no VSCode o caractere aparece. É meio complicado de explicar mas alguns usuários estão reclamando disso pois eles gostam de copiar tudo direto do site e colar nos seus editores de texto porem esse caractere esta vindo junto.

Comment: Você marcou `<meta charset="utf-8">` no `<head>` da página HTML na qual exibe o texto do arquivo codificado em UTF-8, né?

Comment: @jcbrtl creio eu que isso não tem absolutamente nada haver com o problema, mas respondendo sua pergunta, sim eu marquei.

Comment: @AdirKuhn tentei usar o mb_convert_encoding, porém sem sucesso. Na guia principal ele fica de boa, porém no texto-cru ele perde a codificação UTF-8. Guia principal: http://prntscr.com/o8575c Texto cru: http://prntscr.com/o857fc

Comment: o que eh guia principal e texto cru? kkkkk

Comment: @AdirKuhn Guia Principal seria o meu site (me expressei de maneira errada). Texto cru seria o arquivo em si, no caso, o conteudo do arquivo aberto diretamente no navegador, por exemplo, www.site.com/arquivo.txt dessa maneira você abriria o arquivo direto, ou seja, o texto cru do arquivo.

Comment: Infelizmente em nenhum momento você disse que estava querendo visualizar um arquivo estático `.txt` diretamente no navegador, não creio que até a sua ultima edição (a 8 min atrás) alguém iria conseguir deduzir o seu problema e resolve-lo. Só para constar em sua resposta você escreveu `.htacess`, mas tem 2 "c", assim `.htaccess`. Espero que entenda como uma critica construtiva, essa parte de exibir um doc estático diretamente era fundamental para entender, por isso sempre descreva exatamente o que fez.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim eu entendo, eu criei o tópico de maneira errônea. Eu criei o tópico a 9 dias atrás e de la pra cá eu andei estudando diversas coisas e aprendi muita coisa em relação a isso. No dia que eu criei o tópico eu achava que o meu problema estava na hora de salvar o arquivo, mas só depois de um tempo eu acabei descobrindo que na verdade o problema estava na hora de ler o arquivo. Acho que estou devendo um pedido de desculpas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu achava que era impossível modificar a maneira com que o navegador interpreta o arquivo estático, por isso nem comentei sobre essa questão, eu achava que o unico jeito era modificando a maneira de salvar o arquivo kkkkkkk mas como eu falei foi um equivoco meu por falta de conhecimento.

Comment: ps: os downvotes não são meus (nem em nenhuma das respostas), eu só comentei para lhe orientar em futuras perguntas, independente do quanto você entende sobre algo você sempre tem que explicar o passo a passo (ainda sim de forma simples) e explicar aonde exatamente foi exibido que falhou. Boa sorte meu caro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Respondendo as duas perguntas.

.

1) *Existe alguma maneira de forçar o navegador a ler o arquivo em UTF-8 sem a necessidade de adicionar o BOM no arquivo?*

R: Sim, é possível "forçar" o navegador a interpretar o conteúdo do arquivo de texto em UTF-8 adicionando a seguinte regra `Header set Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"` dentro do arquivo **.htaccess** (apache).

*.*

2) *Existe alguma maneira der ler e exibir o conteúdo do arquivo .txt em PHP sem que o BOM seja exibido junto?*

R: Mais ou menos. Não existe nenhum método nativo do PHP para ler o conteúdo do arquivo sem o BOM. Sempre que utilizamos métodos como `file_get_contents()` ou semelhantes, o PHP retorna TODO o conteúdo do arquivo, inclusive o BOM, então para corrigirmos isso podemos fazer uma "gambiarra" removendo o primeiro caractere da String. Exemplo `$texto = substr(file_get_contents("arquivo.txt"), 1);`

Answer (score -2):

Para converter um arquivo para utf 8, use a função [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: :( Não funcionou.  No meu site ele fica de boa, porém no texto-cru do navegador ele perde a codificação UTF-8. Meu site: https://prnt.sc/o8575c Texto cru: https://prnt.sc/o857fc

Answer (score -2):

#### A solução

Crie os arquivos sem BOM, e configure seu servidor web para servir arquivos UTF-8 como padrão. O que está acontecendo é que ele está configurado para outra codificação, ou no caso de não estar configurado, navegadores interpretam os arquivos como ISO-8859-1, que causa má impressão.

Isso porque você está na verdade enfrentando dois problemas diferentes:

#### 1. Um arquivo UTF-8 pode ou não ter BOM

O BOM indica claramente que um arquivo está em UTF-8, mas isso não é *necessário*, para além de nem ser *recomendado*, justamente por causar esse tipo de problema que está tendo. Ver: Ver: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_ordem_de_byte

Então uma possível solução é garantir que está escrevendo um arquivo UTF-8 válido sem BOM.

#### 2. Você controla a página web que exibe esse arquivo?

Se sim, basta acrescentar o código que elimina o BOM. Afinal, é inválido BOM aparecer no meio de qualquer texto. Página web é um texto, e o caracter provavelmente está sendo exibido depois de headers, o que é inválido (numa página texto).

Se não, bem... aponte esse erro a quem controla a página. Mesmo que ele não controle a origem/geração do arquivo, tem de controlar de nunca aparecer o char BOM no meio de um texto.

Comment: Isso que você falou faz todo o sentido, andei dando uma estudada no BOM e descobri que o problema era realmente esse. Eu estou trabalhando com 2 cenários, o primeiro cenário é o MEU SITE, o segundo cenário é o NAVEGADOR. No meu site, o texto do arquivo é exibido normalmente, com ou sem o BOM, porém, caso eu abra o arquivo diretamente no navegador, usando por exemplo, www.site.com/arquivo.txt os caracteres "bugam", caso eu não informe o BOM.

Comment: Se eu NÃO informar o BOM é assim que fica o meu site: https://prnt.sc/o8575c e assim que fica o texto cru no navegador: https://prnt.sc/o857fc . Caso eu informe o BOM, o navegador consegue interpretar tudo normalmente, porém, o meu site fica com aquele problema do ```CTRL + A```  ->  ```CTRL + C```

Comment: Problema de navegador resolve no navegador. Tente essas soluções para ver se resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587629/how-to-force-browser-to-use-utf-8 .

Comment: É impossível eu mexer no navegador. Quando eu falei em "texto cru" no navegador, eu estava me referindo ao fato do navegador abrir e interpretar o arquivo de texto original. Aqui esta um exemplo de arquivo de "texto cru" onde o navegador abre e interpreta o texto https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, a partir do arquivo .htaccess a gente pode forçar o navegador a interpretar em UTF-8 correto? Isso funcionaria em todos os navegadores? Até onde eu sei os arquivos .htaccess só existem nos servidores apache, e se eu estivesse usando servidores Lighttpd ou Nginx

Comment: Não é possível mexer no navegador, mas é possível *instruir* o navegador. Por isso tentar as soluções propostas nesse link, não só da resposta, mas da pergunta também. Sim, funcionaria em todos os navegadores, usar .htaccess ou as outras soluções. Para usar outros servidores, você usa as opções da *pergunta*, que não dependem de dos servidores, ou procurar a instrução equivalente desses servidores.

Comment: Mas o que eu faria mesmo seria servir o arquivo com uma combinação de `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` e depois `fopen` e `fpassthru`.

Comment: Tentei seguir as instruções do tópico que você recomendou e de outros tópicos relacionados porém sem sucesso. Eu adicionei o arquivo .htaccess com as opções recomendadas mas mesmo assim o navegador não interpreta os caracteres em UTF-8. Segue a foto do resultado de como fica: http://prntscr.com/o966y2

Comment: É impossível eu adicionar qualquer linha de código pois o arquivo esta sendo aberto direto no navegador entende? Na pagina do meu site tudo funciona perfeitamente, o problema esta na hora de abrir o arquivo original direto pelo navegador. Voltando a discussão anterior, como eu estava dizendo, se eu adicionar o BOM o navegador interpreta tudo perfeitamente (como pode ver: http://prntscr.com/o9685g). Porém, se eu adicionar o BOM, existe aquele "problema" com o ```CTRL + A``` -> ```CTRL + C```

Comment: Creio eu que o nosso problema então esta em como fazer com que o navegador "abra" os arquivos com a codificação UTF-8 sem o BOM estar escrito no arquivo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95595/discussion-between-andre-lfs-bacci-and-eduardo-mior).

Comment: Acho que consegui resolver o problema adicionando ```Header set Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"``` no .htaccess. Irei fazer mais alguns testes, mas creio eu que isto ira resolver o problema. Assim que possível irei editar o tópico e irei adicionar uma resposta. Parece que o problema esta resolvido. Mas não irei tirar conclusões precipitadas antes de fazer todos os testes.